# Why do I get "C2678 binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type ' const ......."" In this instance?

Tags: c++, math

As part of the project I am building a bit of a math library so I can better learn by implementation rather than using an existing library such as glm. Within this library I have a Vector3 class which is currently throwing a compiler error though I don't understand as to why.

```
uint vertIndex = i * 2;
const Vertex& vSource = data.vertices[i];
Vertex& v1 = result.vertices[vertIndex];
Vertex& v2 = result.vertices[vertIndex + 1];
v1.position = vSource.position;
v2.position = vSource.position + vSource.normal;
v1.colour = v2.colour = Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

The C2678 refers to the second line from the bottom.

Here is the '+' operator overload :

Decleration (.h)

```
Vector3 operator +(const Vector3& rhs);
```

Implementation (.cpp)

```
Vector3 Vector3::operator+(const Vector3 & rhs)
{
    return Add(rhs);
}
```

And just for completeness -> the Add function

```
return Vector3(x + r.x, y + r.y, z + r.z);
```

This resolves the error.

```
inline Vector3 operator +(const Vector3 lhs, const Vector3& rhs){
    //implementation here
}
```

So my question is.... Should I overload all operators this way as opposed to the way I was doing it before. Why is there no implicit conversion for the previous method?

Comment: That's because `vSource` is a reference to a *constant* object, which means all the member function called on it need to marked as `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator should be overloaded as such:

#### Declaration (.h)

```
Vector3 operator +(const Vector3& rhs) const;
```

#### Implementation (.cpp)

```
Vector3 Vector3::operator+(const Vector3 & rhs) const
{
    return Add(rhs);
}
```

#### Explanation

The `const` declaration, when appended to the method's prototype, indicates that the properties of the object on which the method is called will not be altered by the method's execution.

**N.B.:** the `Add` method should also be marked as `const`.